# How to split gitlab-ci.yml to make it possible to run some scripts within one GitLab repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm looking for a way how to split gitlab-ci.yml to make it possible to run some scripts within one GitLab repository.

I have some .py and .ps scripts in my git repository. I'd like to setup a scheduler to execute some of them at specific time. But sometimes I need to execute some other scripts manually.
As far as I understand, it is possible to have only 1 pipeline within 1 repository. So, it seems, I can't cover all necessary scenarios within a single pipeline to run different scripts depends on needs.

Is there any possible solution to get this possible?
I'm novice in Git CI, so all advices will be useful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create [schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) in gitlab. And you can specifiy jobs to run in schedules or not (see section "Using only and except" in the link above).

So you can mix scheduled tasks and manually triggered task in one pipeline (which effectively get two or more pipelines).